# Need solution to swipe video

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a series of pictures/videos on a mobile phone viewport, i added the function swipeleft/right to let user browse, working fine for just images, but once it show a video, i am unable to swipe the video anymore. Any tips on how i can resolve it? Thanks.

```
$('.sectionTwo_mainPic').on("swipeleft", function(event){   
    counter ++; 
    var thumbImgSrc= $(".portfolioThumb:eq("+counter+")").attr("src");
    resetBigDisplay();
    console.log("swiped left");
    $(this).append('<img class="imgSrc" src="'+thumbImgSrc+'">');

    $(".hint").show();
    var bigImageTotal = $(".has-sub.active .sectionTwo_thumbnail img").length;
    console.log("total is " + bigImageTotal);           
    console.log("counter = " + counter);

    if(counter == bigImageTotal ){
        counter = 0;
    }

    var urlCheck = $(".has-sub.active img:eq("+counter+")").attr("src");
    var checkIfYoutube = "youtube";
    console.log("urlCheck is : "+urlCheck);

    /* if the thumbnail src contain img from youtube, then retrieve id and display video
    ================================================== */
    if(urlCheck.indexOf(checkIfYoutube) > 1){
        resetBigDisplay();
        console.log('youtube found');
        var parts = urlCheck.split('/');
        var youtubeSrc = "http://www.youtube.com/v/"
        var mainVideo = youtubeSrc + parts[4];

        $(this).append('<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"><iframe class="embed-responsive-item videoSrc" src="'+mainVideo+' "</iframe></div>">');

        $("#sectionTwo_mainPic .video").show().siblings().hide();
    }
    else {
        console.log('youtube not found');
    }
});         


$('.sectionTwo_mainPic').on("swiperight", function(event){  
    resetBigDisplay();
    counter = counter -1;
    console.log("counter is now " + counter);
    var thumbImgSrc= $(".portfolioThumb:eq("+counter+")").attr("src");

    console.log("swiped right");
    $(this).append('<img class="imgSrc" src="'+thumbImgSrc+'">');

    var urlCheck = $(".has-sub.active img:eq("+counter+")").attr("src");
    var checkIfYoutube = "youtube";
    console.log("urlCheck is : "+urlCheck);

    /* if the thumbnail src contain img from youtube, then retrieve id and display video
    ================================================== */
    if(urlCheck.indexOf(checkIfYoutube) > 1){
        resetBigDisplay();
        console.log('youtube found');
        var parts = urlCheck.split('/');
        var youtubeSrc = "http://www.youtube.com/v/"
        var mainVideo = youtubeSrc + parts[4];

        $(this).append('<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"><iframe class="embed-responsive-item videoSrc" src="'+mainVideo+' "</iframe></div>">');

        $("#sectionTwo_mainPic .video").show().siblings().hide();
    }
    else {
        console.log('youtube not found');
    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We have a similar problem in our App. We have currently solved it by showing a preview image instead of the video, and when the user loads the video by clicking on the preview image, we display alternative controls - a left and right button, so he can switch pages.

We are searching for a better solution too.